# ServiceStack ORMLite JoinAlias on a Where clause

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack, predicatebuilder

I'm trying to add a Where clause to a table joined with a JoinAlias, but there doesn't appear to be a way to specify the JoinAlias on the where clause.

I'm trying to join to the same table multiple times, then add a variable number of where clauses to the join, based on user input:

```
  var userFilterList = new List<Expression<Func<LocationDb, LocationAttributesDateTimeDb, bool>>>();

  Expression <Func<LocationDb, LocationAttributesDateTimeDb, bool>> joinPredicate = (loc, ext) =>
            loc.LocationId == ext.LocationId && ext.AttributeId == attributeId;

  query = query.Join<LocationAttributesDateTimeDb>(joinPredicate, ctx.JoinAlias($"ext{attributeId}"));


  foreach (var item in userFilterList)
  {
       query = query.Where<LocationDb, LocationAttributesDateTimeDb>(item);
  }
```

The main problem is, there doesn't appear to be a way to add the JoinAlias onto the Where clause. If I try to run the query as is, I get an exception regarding the missing alias.

If I try the following code, I get a compile exception:

```
query = query.Where<LocationDb, LocationAttributesDateTimeDb>(item, ctx.JoinAlias($"ext{attributeId}"));
```

Is there a way to add the JoinAlias to a where clause without resorting to writing the Where clauses as manual SQL?

Or, is there an alternative method I can use to stitch my multiple requests together into the single Join predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the latest [v5.4.1 pre-release on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) `JoinAlias()` has been deprecated and replaced with `TableAlias()` which uses a different implementation that substitutes the alias whilst walking the expression tree whilst generating SQL Statements whereas `JoinAlias()` worked by post string substitution on the generated SQL which was more fragile.

There's no `TableAlias()` in WHERE statements as it wouldn't be possible to determine where the alias should be used, instead here are some examples of [how to use TableAlias in WHERE](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/1ef91856b87fe9127873b06c73b38fcbd0baf8d9/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/Issues/JoinAliasIntIssue.cs) conditions:

```
q.Where<Team, Teamuser>((t, u) => t.Id == Sql.TableAlias(u.TeamId, "Leader"));
q.Where<Teamuser>(u => Sql.TableAlias(u.Id, "Leader") == 1);
q.Where<Team, Teamuser>((t, u) => Sql.TableAlias(t.Id, q.DialectProvider.GetQuotedTableName(ModelDefinition<Team>.Definition)) == Sql.TableAlias(u.TeamId, "Leader")); // Workaround, but only works for fields, not constants
q.Where<Team, Teamuser>((user, leader) => Sql.TableAlias(user.Id, "Teamuser") < Sql.TableAlias(leader.Id, "Leader"));
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped to clarify. I couldn't get my head around why there was no way of adding the TableAlias directly to the where clause, but it makes sense that it needs to be against a specific column.

Comment: I don't see any examples in your code of how you would do string comparisons. I've managed to get everything working except that.

For example:

q.Where<Teamuser>(u => Sql.TableAlias(u.LastName, "Leader").StartsWith("Mac"));
q.Where<Teamuser>(u => Sql.TableAlias(u.LastName.StartsWith("Mac"), "Leader"));

Neither of these options work. Is there a way to do string comparisons?